# How can I change the bandpass filter of fluxes/magnitudes to a synthetic filter?

Tags: python, filter, flux, astronomy, magnitude

I have a data set containing Supernova light curve data in u, g,r,i, z and y bands - AB mags similar to SDSS (flux, times and some metadata like redshift and distance modulus). I would like to transform all of them to a synthetic filter centered at 4000 angstrom with an equivalent width of 800 angstrom. How do I go about doing it ?
I found a couple of codes such as synphot and pyphot in which you can create synthetic band passes. But I don't understand how to do the transformation. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.